# WHERE clause not hitting on LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select `ID`, `a`, `b` from `DatabaseAlpha` whose `IS_CURRENT = 'y'`, along with any data from `DatabaseBravo` who has the same `ID` as `DatabaseAlpha` and whose field `IS_CURRENT = 'Y'`. I am using a `LEFT JOIN` because all `ID`s in `DatabaseBravo` will have a corresponding one in `DatabaseAlpha`. But not all `ID`s in `DatabaseAlpha` will have on in `DatabaseBravo` (hence, I expect `NULLS` to return in the query on the right side). There will only be one instance of `IS_CURRENT = 'Y'` per `ID` (but multiple `IS_CURRENT = 'N'`).

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT ID, a, b 
FROM DatabaseAlpha x
LEFT JOIN DatabaseBravo y ON x.ID = y.ID
                          AND x.IS_CURRENT = 'Y' 
                          AND y.IS_CURRENT = 'Y'
```

However, the result is not what I want. This query is showing multiple entries with the SAME `ID` from my `DatabaseAlpha` table and `NULL` from `DatabaseBravo`, having both `IS_CURRENT = 'Y'` and `IS_CURRENT = 'N'`.

For example, take `ID = 357`. There are 6 entries in `DatabaseAlpha` with this `ID`, and zero in `DatabaseBravo`. Of the 6 entries, 5 of them have `IS_CURRENT = 'N'` and only one has `IS_CURRENT = 'Y'`. The result I want is for only the entry with `IS_CURRENT = 'Y'` to return for this ID. However, the actual result from the query is that all 6 entries are returned, including the ones that say `IS_CURRENT = 'N'`.

I've tried changing my query in three ways, but they all failed:

```
WHERE x.IS_CURRENT = 'Y' AND y.IS_CURRENT = 'Y'
WHERE x.IS_CURRENT = 'Y' OR y.IS_CURRENT = 'Y'
AND x.IS_CURRENT = 'Y' OR y.IS_CURRENT = 'Y'
```

What am I doing wrong or not seeing here?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Your first query looks like it should work.  If it doesn't it's probably because of something that you've removed from the real query for this question.

Comment: Referencing your table in the `LEFT JOIN` like that in the `WHERE` effectively turns your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. `WHERE NULL {= / > / < /Boolean Operator} {expression}` will always equal `unknown`, and `unknown != true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move part of the `join` condition to `where` criteria instead:

```
SELECT ID, a, b 
FROM DatabaseAlpha x
    LEFT JOIN DatabaseBravo y on x.ID = y.ID and y.IS_CURRENT = 'Y'
WHERE x.IS_CURRENT = 'Y'
```

This will return all records from the `DatabaseAlpha` table that match on `is_current = 'Y'` and because you are using an `outer join`, only those matching from the `join` condition will be returned from `DatabaseBravo`, in this case `is_current = 'Y'` there as well.